# MySQL Workbench not connection to local host

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have came across similar questions, but not with any solutions.  I can't make a connection from within MySQL workbench to my local server (127.0.0.1). I also tried changing it to "localhost".  I get the error "Can't Connect to Server".

I made sure the service was started.  I then tried using the MySQL console and when I enter the password there it connects without any issues.  I exit, go back in to the Workbench and it still won't connect. I tried editing the connection and pressing clear on the vault.  No luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after uninstalling and reinstalling.  I realized the port it was originally setup on was already in use with a local instance of WordPress I had setup.  During the reinstall I found another available port, created the server at the new location, and changed the connection in the workbench to reflect the new port.

If anyone else comes across this and wants to see what ports they have available to setup a new connection on, just open a command prompt and type "netstat -an" without the quotes to see a list.